# Theming Android App with reference to color

Tags: android, styles, themes

I want to offer my user two themes: light and dark. I want the background color of a certain layout to change based on whichever theme has been chosen.

Essentially, I want to have two themes like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Light">
    <item name="myBackgroundColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Dark">
    <item name="myBackgroundColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

And then from my Activity, I would reference the variable like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="?myBackgroundColor"/>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured out an answer of sorts. **If anyone has a better answer, please post it.**

You need to declare the attribute "myBackgroundColor" as styleable. E.G:

```
<declare-styleable name="TestStyleable">
    <attr name="myBackgroundColor" format="color|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I have no idea what the name refers to, it seems you can set it to anything. Once you have declared this block, you can use "myBackgroundColor" as I have done above.